# Make TSLint lint Vue Component template

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tslint, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt, and I have the following Vue.js component :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Page 
            :total="total" 
            show-sizer 
            @on-change="pageChanged"
            @on-page-size-change='pageSizeChanged'> //should trigger linter error
        </Page>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
...
</script>
```

And I want my linter to warn me if I use single quotes inside Vue.js components, and also to apply my typescript rules to my typescript code.

Even though i searched, i wasn't able to find a way to make my linter work with both.

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: There's a dedicated vs code plugin for using vue with tslint but I don't know how well it works as I haven't used it much.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I guess it's this one ? https://github.com/prograhammer/vscode-tslint-vue

Comment: Quite so, I would give it a try